# Is it possible to read a shell command's output from nvi's command line?

Tags: shell, nvi

I was trying see if I can integrate *fzf* with *nvi*, but couldn't find a way to do something like `:Edit <shell command's output>` which would solve my problem.

I tried `:source nvi.ex` -- it works for a normal file; but when I do  `mkfifo nvi.ex` and then `:source nvi.ex`, **nothing** happens even though it waits till I write into the *fifo*.

I wrote into the *fifo* like this:

1. `cat - >> nvi.ex`
2. `Edit README` followed by an <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd>

Are there cases where a programs treats a *fifo* differently compared to a normal file?

PS: This works in *vi* and *vim* though! *nvi* version is 1.79.

Comment: What about `:read !cmd` ?

Comment: Thanks @D.BenKnoble, I will revisit this sometime later; I haven't been using nvi for a while now due to lack of time. Will update you.

Answer (score 0):

1. `fzf` has a vim plugin [here](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim) that might work for you
2. vim users might try [clam from Steve Losh](https://github.com/sjl/clam.vim)
3. Vim (not sure about nvi) has a `:redir` command that can be used to accomplish similar results.

Comment: Hey, my question is on using *fzf* in *nvi* by Keith Bostic :-)

Comment: @Nishant I’m aware—just trying to help others that may come across similar needs